# How to work on Wowza media Engine in Aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wowza

We have ios mobile app application..We need to implement video streaming in wowza media  Engine.How to  work on Wowza media Engine  in Aws

Comment: create a wowza instance , either you can use your own license or you can use amazon ec2 software fee. create a live application and encode to wowza.

Comment: We have finished our project.we have using many Web Server in our project and also we have used AWS S3 server to save the media files.we have run app in web & Android & IOS deceives. That time videos are taking long time to play in our application. we are planning to use Wowza Streaming Engine for video streaming. But We don't no to connect the Wowza Streaming Engine to AWS S3 server

Comment: There is a way for optimise delivery if you have finished the project then no need.

Comment: We have received  video slow issue from users. that only we are like to implement the Video Stream method. 

 is RTMP Distributions is best for video streaming   ?

Comment: For delivery hls or mpegdash is best

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like you are trying to stream VOD files from a web server or S3 bucket, it's best to use the Wowza Streaming Engine MediaCache functionality. This is a more optimal way of streaming content that is not located locally. On initial player request, it grabs the specified number of blocks from the remote location and caches the segments locally, which it then serves to all subsequent player requests.

To use MediaCache, you need to first create the MediaCache store (where the cached content is stored) and the MediaCache sources (where your Wowza server will obtain the remote content). MediaCache sources can be a Cloud storage provider (currently AWS S3, Google Cloud or Microsoft Azure), a file server, or a web server. Each of these sources are identified with a prefix (for example, amazons3). You will then need to create a VOD Edge type of application which can access these MediaCache sources.

If your application name is vodedge, and you are streaming sample.mp4 from your amazons3 source, your example playback URL would then be:
`http://localhost:1935/vodedge/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8`

Note that you need to include the application instance (default is `_definst_`).

The playback formats that you choose is really dependent on your target audience and players. Mobile devices don't support RTMP unless you use an app (like the VLC mobile app). But if you know that your target audience will only be using desktop, you control these machines (such as in an internal corporate network) where you can install the required plugins, and latency is a paramount requirement, then RTMP might be a better choice for you, as RTMP is a streaming protocol and is inherently less latent.

If you do need to stream to mobile devices and latency is important, you can opt to tweak the HTTP streaming packetization in your Wowza server so that your target chunk durations are shorter. You can do this by selecting your Wowza live application, and selecting the Properties tab (possible only if you have enabled Advanced Settings on your Manager UI account). Do note that Apple spec recommends a 10-second segment length (which is the Wowza default), and you may run into bandwidth issues as requests for the chunks would be more frequent.